# Is there a way to avoid adding (///<reference path="..."/>) when compiling to single '*.js' file with TypeScript 1.8 compiler

Tags: typescript

Here is the problem currently when we want to split our code into multiple '*.ts' files and then output a single '*.js' file we still will have to add to each '*.ts' file (///reference...) when we want to work with class/functions defined in some other '*.ts' file. This does not make sense since in the end we will have all Typescript class definitions merged into a single JavaScript file. The only reason this (///reference...) is required is to help the compiler order this class definitions into the generated JavaScript files based on the proper order of usage. Is there a way to make the Typescript compiler order properly the class definitions inside the single generated JavaScript file instead of us manually entering (///reference...) across multiple Typescript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the Typescript compiler order properly the class definitions inside the single generated JavaScript file instead of us manually entering (///) across multiple Typescript files

Not if you are not using modules. TypeScript doesn't have intrinsic knowledge of the right ordering (fundamentally because there isn't a `main` function like there is in a C# program). Not saying that *it absolutetly can't* but it *definitely doesn't*.

PS : outFile is bad if you don't use modules https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: Yes thanks I feared there is no way :(. Lets hope Typescript compiler becomes smarter since it looks like exactly the job of the compiler. A parameter which will point to the application's starting point (or main function) as you pointed out could be added easily. This will save us a lot of boilerplate code and basically will make outFile really easy to use without much of the negative effects described in your link.